# Lightning Components on salesforce mobile app refresh issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-quickaction, salesforce-mobile-app

I have an issue with Lightning components in Salesforce Mobile. I have an implementation where I launch a component from a quick action button on a record page (The component uses the record's data). However after finishing with the component, I want to run that same action on another record. When I do this, it takes me to the old instance of the component with the previous data entered and the exact previous state. Is there a way to avoid this? I have to refresh every time to avoid this and it is bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try firing the `e.force:refreshView` event after your data change occurs. This event will cause components on the page to refresh themselves, without causing a full page refresh and loading all of the framework code.

Comment: This doesn't work. I already tried. The issue is not the refresh, I am trying to load another instance of the same component. It is launched via quick action on the record.

Comment: My first thought is to clear out the properties on your quick action component after saving. That way the next time it runs it's "fresh" again. Can you verify if the record ID changes when you run the quick action for the next record?

Comment: There is no way to tell if it changes on mobile. I could try using alert but since relaunching thst component goes to the old one, it wouldn't even output the alert

Answer (score 0):

Something to check: When you open the action from another record, does `v.recordId` change to the new record's value? If so you might be able to put a change handler on that attribute and use it to trigger a refresh.